# Attaching objects retrieved from multiple sources

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three classes, Fish (which contains two properties of type Chips and MushyPeas respectively), MushyPeas (which contains a property of type Chips) and Chips (which has a Name property).

I am running the following piece of hypothetical code:

```
int chipsId;
using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    var creationChips = new Chips() { Name = "A portion of chips" };
    db.Chips.Add(creationChips);
    db.SaveChanges();
    chipsId = creationChips.ChipsId;
}

Chips retrievedChips1;
using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    retrievedChips1 = db.Chips.Where(x => x.ChipsId == chipsId).ToList()[0];
}

Chips retrievedChips2;
using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    retrievedChips2 = db.Chips.Where(x => x.ChipsId == chipsId).ToList()[0];
}

using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    db.Chips.Attach(retrievedChips1);
    db.Chips.Attach(retrievedChips2);

    var mushyPeas = new MushyPeas() { Chips = retrievedChips2 };

    var fish = new Fish() { Chips = retrievedChips1, MushyPeas = mushyPeas };
    db.Fish.Add(fish);
    db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is to simulate a situation in my real app, in which EF objects (which may actually represent the same database record) are loaded from a variety of different DbContexts and then added to an object tree in another DbContext.

If I don't call the two db.Chips.Attach lines, then brand new Chips entities are created when the Fish object is saved to the database, and assigned new IDs.

Calling db.Chips.Attach solves this issue for one of the retrieved obejcts, but the second Attach call fails with the exception "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

What is the best way to achieve what I want to achieve here?

Comment: FYI, if you use just one DbContext for longer lifetime, there is no harm because DbContext does not keep DB Connection all the time, only for query and saving changes it opens & closes database connection. Having multiple context simply increases complexity.

Answer (score 1):

As a grizzled EF vet, I've come to the conclusion that it's best to avoid using `Attach` in many cases.

The exception `"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"` is usually misleading since the object that you're trying to attach isn't actually attached to the data context.  What happens when you attach an object is it recursively attaches any entities that it references.  So, if you attach an entity to the data context, and then attach another entity that references any entity that was *implicitly* attached previously, you will get this error.  The solution is pretty simple:

```
using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    var chips1 = db.Chips.Find(retrievedChips1.Id);
    var chips2 = db.Chips.Find(retrievedChips2.Id);

    var mushyPeas = new MushyPeas() { Chips = chips2 };

    var fish = new Fish() { Chips = chips1, MushyPeas = mushyPeas };
    db.Fish.Add(fish);
    db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This guarantees that both entities will be attached to the data context without any sort of ObjectStateManager issues.

Comment: That is indeed the drawback to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the `Local` collection to check if an entity with the same key is already attached and if yes, use the attached entity:

```
using (var db = new FishContext())
{
    var attachedChips1 = db.Chips.Local
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChipsId == retrievedChips1.ChipsId);
    if (attachedChips1 == null)
    {
        db.Chips.Attach(retrievedChips1);
        attachedChips1 = retrievedChips1;
    }

    var attachedChips2 = db.Chips.Local
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChipsId == retrievedChips2.ChipsId);
    if (attachedChips2 == null)
    {
        db.Chips.Attach(retrievedChips2);
        attachedChips2 = retrievedChips2;
    }

    var mushyPeas = new MushyPeas() { Chips = attachedChips2 };

    var fish = new Fish() { Chips = attachedChips1, MushyPeas = mushyPeas };

    //...
}
```

(The first check doesn't make sense in this simple example because a new context is empty with nothing attached to it. But you get the idea...)

However, in the case that you also want to update the related entities (for example by setting the state to `Modified` after attaching) it would be a problem if `retrievedChips1` and `retrievedChips2` have (except the key value) different property values. You had to decide somehow which is the "correct one". But that would be business logic. You just have to hand over one of them to EF and only one. In your scenario it wouldn't matter which one you use because you are only creating a relationship and for this EF will only care about the key value.

Side note: Instead of `...ToList()[0]` the more natural way would be `...First()` (or `Single()` in this case because you are querying the key).

Comment: This won't work because the issue isn't that attachedChips1 or attachedChips2 are already attached to the context, it's that attachedChips2 references an entity that attachedChips1 also references, that had already been recursively attached during the first call to `Attach`.  The same issue would exist with your solution.

Comment: @w.brian: He is loading `retrievedChips1` and `retrievedChips2` without navigation properties, so there are no other entities that are referenced and my code above would solve the problem in the question's example. For the more general case you are right, the exception can be caused by related entities and the real source of the problem can be much more hidden.

Comment: It's a contrived example per his original post.  The code in his example wouldn't fail for the same reason you state.

Comment: @w.brian: *Exactly* the code in the question will fail because it is attaching two different objects with the same key.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  Yes, your solution is correct if that is in fact what's going on in his actual scenario, but chances are he's confused by the exception.